# Web Api - É errado obter um objeto relacionado assim?

Tags: c#, web-service, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Comecei desenvolver com Web Api (asp.net Core) e estou com uma duvida quanto a esta certo ou errado o que estou fazendo...

Tenho duas classes em 1 para N:

A classe Department:

```
public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Seller> Sellers { get; set; } = new List<Seller>();
    }
```

E a classe Seller:

```
public class Seller
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public double BaseSalary { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SalesRecord> Sales { get; set; }
   }
```

E tenho uma terceira classe chamada DpId que Herda de Seller e tem uma propriedade Int:

```
public class DpId : Seller
    {
        public int dpId { get; set; }

    }
```

---

**Minha duvida aparece agora:**

Tenho um Controller para Seller onde no método Post eu estou fazendo da seguinte forma para poder cadastrar um Seller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult<Seller> insertSeller(DpId item)
        {
            item.Department = _dpService.findById(item.dpId);
            _sellerService.insert(item);
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Como podem ver, para cadastrar um Seller, eu estou obtendo o Department para a classe Seller usando dpId que veio no parâmetro e só então eu cadastro.

Isso é errado? Tem forma melhor?

Eu comecei mexer com Web Api a pouco tempo, se tiver um bom tutorial poderia me passe (já vi o tutorial de web api do docs.microsoft)

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você quer somente adicionar um novo Seller, certo? Existe mesmo a necessidade de você ter uma terceira entidade somente com um ID? Eu declararia o ID na própria entidade Seller. Quando for respondido esse questionamento, eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: É pq eu estou adicionando um Seller + um department para esse Seller e pra não criar uma sobrecarga que recebe com DepartmentId eu resolvi fazer assim, só não sei se isso é certo